# jQuery "keyup" crashing page when checking 'Word Count'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I have a word counter running on a DIV and after typing in a few words, the page crashes. The browser continues to work (par scrolling) and no errors are showing in Chrome's console. Not sure where I'm going wrong...

It all started when I passed "*wordCount(q);*" in "*keyup*". I only passed it there as it would split-out "NaN" instead of a number to countdown from.

JS:

```
wordCount();

$('#group_3_1').click(function(){
    var spliced = 200;
    wordCount(spliced);
}) ;

$('#group_3_2').click(function(){
    var spliced = 600;
    wordCount(spliced);
}) ;

function wordCount(q) {
    var content_text = $('.message1').text(),
        char_count = content_text.length;

        if (char_count != 0) 
          var word_count = q - content_text.replace(/[^\w ]/g, "").split(/\s+/).length;
        $('.word_count').html(word_count + " words remaining...");

        $('.message1').keyup(function() {
          wordCount(q);
        });

        try
        {
            if (new Number( word_count ) < 0) {
                $(".word_count").attr("id","bad");
            }
            else {
                $(".word_count").attr("id","good");
            }
        } catch (error)
        {
            //
        }

  };
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="entry.3.group" value="1/6" class="size1" id="group_3_1">
<input type="checkbox" name="entry.3.group" value="1/4" class="size1" id="group_3_2">


<div id="entry.8.single" class="message1" style="height: 400px; overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden;" contenteditable="true"> </div>
<span class="word_count" id="good"></span>
```

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Where is your wordCount() function?

Comment: Just a doubt..Why are you registering keyup inside wordCount() function?

Comment: You're running an infinite loop when the `keyup` event is triggered in the content editable element - that is why the browser crashes.

Comment: What if the user didn't clicked any checkbox? What will be the default value for word_count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do probably something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/6WW7Z/2/

```
var wordsLimit = 50;

$('#group_3_1').click(function () {
    wordsLimit = 200;
    wordCount();
});
$('#group_3_2').click(function () {
    wordsLimit = 600;
    wordCount();
});
$('.message1').keydown(function () {
    wordCount();
});

function wordCount() {
    var text = $('.message1').text(),
        textLength = text.length,
        wordsCount = 0,
        wordsRemaining = wordsLimit;

    if(textLength > 0) {
        wordsCount = text.replace(/[^\w ]/g, '').split(/\s+/).length;
        wordsRemaining = wordsRemaining - wordsCount;
    }
    $('.word_count')
        .html(wordsRemaining + " words remaining...")
        .attr('id', (parseInt(wordsRemaining) < 0 ? 'bad' : 'good'));

};  

wordCount();
```

It's not perfect and complete but it may show you direction how to do this. You should use change event on checkboxes to change wordsLimit if checked/unchecked. For styling valid/invalid *words remaining* message use classes rather than ids.

Comment: you should use an event on the keypress function to test for a certain key.

Comment: thank you so much @f1ames !! Exactly what is was after. Thank you so much for your quick reply :)

Answer (score 2):

This is causing an infinite loop `if (new Number(word_count) < 0) {`.

Your code is a mess altogether. Just study and start with more basic concepts and start over. If you want to describe your project to me in a comment, I would be glad to show you a good, clean, readable approach.

**Update:**
Part of having a good architecture in your code is to keep different parts of your logic separate. No part of your code should know about or use anything that isn't directly relevant to it. Notice in my word counter that anything it does it immediately relevant to its word-counter-ness. Does a word counter care about what happens with the count? Nope. It just counts and sends the result away (wherever you tell it to, via the callback function). This isn't the only approach, but I just wanted to give you an idea of how to approach things more sensefully.

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/uxOYODIT/3/edit)

```
/* what am I creating? A word counter.
 * How do I want to use it?
 * -Call a function, passing in an element and a callback function
 * -Bind the word counter to that element
 * -When the word count changes, pass the new count to the callback function
 */

window.onload = function() {
  var countDiv = document.getElementById('count');
  wordCounter.bind(countDiv, displayCount);
  //you can pass in whatever function you want. I made one called displayCount, for example
};

var wordCounter = {
  current : 0,
  bind : function(elem, callback) {
    this.ensureEditable(elem);
    this.handleIfChanged(elem, callback);

    var that = this;
    elem.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
      that.handleIfChanged(elem, callback);
    });
  },
  handleIfChanged : function(elem, callback) {
    var count = this.countWords(elem);
    if (count !== this.current) {
      this.current = count;
      callback(count);
    }
  },
  countWords : function(elem) {
    var text = elem.textContent;
    var words = text.match(/(\w+\b)/g);
    return (words) ? words.length : 0;
  },
  ensureEditable : function(elem) {
    if (
      elem.getAttribute('contenteditable') !== 'true' && 
      elem.nodeName !== 'TEXTAREA' &&
      elem.nodeName !== 'INPUT'
    ) {
      elem.setAttribute('contenteditable', true); 
    }
  }
};

var display = document.getElementById('display');
function displayCount(count) {
  //this function is called every time the word count changes
  //do whatever you want...the word counter doesn't care.
  display.textContent = 'Word count is: '+count;
}
```

Comment: Hi @m59, I'm still a bit new at working with variables outside of functions.It's actually a combination of 2 code segments found on Stack Overflow. When I split the code up so the variable was given via a selection of a checkbox, thats when it got a bit messy and working with existing code isn't helping I guess!!

Comment: You need to stop copying other people's code, especially if you don't understand it. In the time you have spent debugging this mess, you could have learned to write better code than what you copied. I am updating my answer..I think this will help you. @MichaelMarchment

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `radio` in place of `checkboxes` because you can limit `200` or `600` only at a time.

Try this like,

```
wordCount();
$('input[name="entry.3.group"]').click(function () {
    wordCount();
    $('.word_count').html($(this).data('val') + " words remaining...");
});
$('.message1').keyup(function () {
    wordCount();    
});

function wordCount() {
    var q = $('input[name="entry.3.group"]:checked').data('val');
    var content_text = $('.message1').text(),
        char_count = content_text.length;
    if (char_count != 0) var word_count = q - content_text.replace(/[^\w ]/g, "").split(/\s+/).length;
    $('.word_count').html(word_count + " words remaining...");
    try {
        if (Number(word_count) < 0) {
            $(".word_count").attr("id", "bad");
        } else {
            $(".word_count").attr("id", "good");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        //
    }    
};
```

Also you can add if your `span` has `bad id` then `key up` should `return false;`

See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L84Q3/)

Comment: That would actually be quick a logical solution! haha. I'm working with a google doc created by a client so I will look into changing that all around. Cheers @rohan-kumar